# How can I change Alfredo Barco's Test Store in Paypal

Tags: javascript, paypal

I am trying to integrate PayPal express checkout in my website  I've seen a demo in developer PayPal website and it works properly but somehow I cannot able to edit the content of it. Specifically the *Alfredo Barco's Test Store*. Is it possible to change it? And how? Thank You.

[image]

```
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>

<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

<script>

    // Render the PayPal button

    paypal.Button.render({

        // Set your environment

        env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production

        // Specify the style of the button

        style: {
            label: 'buynow',
            fundingicons: true, // optional
            branding: true, // optional
            size:  'small', // small | medium | large | responsive
            shape: 'rect',   // pill | rect
            color: 'gold'   // gold | blue | silve | black
        },

        // PayPal Client IDs - replace with your own
        // Create a PayPal app: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/create

        client: {
            sandbox:    'AZDxjDScFpQtjWTOUtWKbyN_bDt4OgqaF4eYXlewfBP4-8aqX3PiV8e1GWU6liB2CUXlkA59kJXE7M6R',
            production: '<insert production client id>'
        },

        // Wait for the PayPal button to be clicked

        payment: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.payment.create({
                transactions: [
                    {
                        amount: { total: '0.01', currency: 'USD' }
                    }
                ]
            });
        },

        // Wait for the payment to be authorized by the customer

        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
                window.alert('Payment Complete!');
            });
        }

    }, '#paypal-button-container');

</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it.

**First** way way is to go to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessprofile/settings/ and the business name that you see is what you see "Alfredo Barco"

**Second** way is to use - look at this object
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#definition-payee_display_metadata
it is part of https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#definition-transaction within payee object.

if you pass in a brand name as part of this object it will override what you have in your settings.

**Third** way is to use
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payment-experience/ and use
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payment-experience/#definition-presentation and pass the name you want as part of the "brand name"

this api creates an experience profile id which is what you can pass as part of your Create Payment call.